# Removing simple Relationships in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Good Evening,

I am using SDN 3, and am running into problems with removing simple relationships (RelateTo) in my underlying graph. The scenario is that I want to establish a Friend request/approval system amongst Users in my web application. I have no problem issuing the request by creating a "HAS_REQUESTED" relationship between Users. but once the User receiving the friend request hits "approve", the "FRIENDS_WITH" relationship is established without properly removing the "HAS_REQUESTED" relationship. the code below walks through the process:

The relevant Controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/approve/friend/{friendId}")
public String approveFriend(@PathVariable("friendId") String friendId){
    User me = userService.findByEmail(userService.getAuthenticatedUser().getName());
    userService.removeOldRequests(friendId, me);
    userService.approveFriendship(friendId, me);
    return "redirect:/friends";
}
```

The UserService method in question. 'me' is the authenticated user who originally sent the friend request to 'friendId/friend':

```
public void removeOldRequests(String friendId, User me){
try{
    User friend = userRepository.findByUserId(friendId);
    friend.addStartNodeForUsersRequestingMe(me, false);
    template.save(friend);
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and here is my User entity Node (excluding unrelated fields/getters/setters.)

```
@NodeEntity
```

public class User {

```
@GraphId Long nodeId;
@Indexed
String userId;
String username;
String firstName;
String lastName;
String email;
String aboutMe;
String Quote;
String favoriteBook;
int age;
Date userCreation;
String sex;
String password;
Role role;
byte[] picture;


@RelatedTo(type="FRIENDS_WITH", direction=Direction.BOTH)
@Fetch
Set<User> friends;


@RelatedTo(type="HAS_FRIEND_REQUEST")
@Fetch
Set<User> startNodeForUsersRequestingMe;

@RelatedTo(type="HAS_FRIEND_REQUEST", direction=Direction.INCOMING)
@Fetch
Set<User> UsersWhoHaveRequestedMe;


public void addStartNodeForUsersRequestingMe(User user, boolean flag){
    if(flag){
        this.startNodeForUsersRequestingMe.add(user);
    }else{
        this.startNodeForUsersRequestingMe.remove(user);
    }

}
public void addUsersWhoHaveRequestedMe(User user, boolean flag){
    if(flag){
        this.UsersWhoHaveRequestedMe.add(user);
    }else{
        this.UsersWhoHaveRequestedMe.remove(user);
    }

}
```

The repository method I am using to return the current user's friend requests is below. Right now it is configured to just return any relationship the user has that is "HAS_FRIEND_REQUEST" just for testing purposes to see if I can get User A with one friend request from User B to NOT be returned.

```
@Query("START user=node({0})"
    +"MATCH (user)-[:HAS_FRIEND_REQUEST]-(friend)"
    + "return friend;")
```

Iterable getUserFriendRequests(User user);

Any guidance on how to properly remove the "HAS_FRIEND_REQUEST" in a clean manner would be greatly appreciated. either that, or maybe a better way to handle the "friend request Handshake" idea. If you have any questions or concerns for me, please do not hesitate to bring them to my attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the target user from the collection 
or use the Neo4jTemplate method to delete the relationship.

`template.deleteRelationshipBetween(Object start, Object end, String type)`

Comment: That worked like a charm. I previously tried the template.deleteRelationshipBetween method, and It continued to fail. I had to be sure I was actually putting the parameters in the right direction. 

my correct implementation ended up being : 


`public void removeOldRequests(String friendId, User me){
 User friend = userRepository.findByUserId(friendId);
 try{
  template.deleteRelationshipBetween(friend, me, "HAS_FRIEND_REQUEST");
 }catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
 
}`

Thanks again for the help!