# Removing relationship between two nodes in Spring Boot 2.4.3 Neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I'm in the middle of upgrading from Spring Boot 2.3 to 2.4 and are having some issues with Neo4j after upgrade.

I'm creating two nodes, and adding a relationship between them

```
@Node
class Document(
    @Id
    val id: String,
) {
    @Relationship(type = "CONCERNS")
    var concerns: Concerns? = null
}

@RelationshipProperties
class Concerns(
    @TargetNode val user: User
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private var id: Long? = null
}

@Node
class User(
    @Id
    val id: String
) {
    var givenName: String? = null
    var familyName: String? = null
}
```

Creating the Nodes and adding the relationship works fine

[image]

But when I try to remove the relationship from the user, nothing happens:

```
val document = documentRepository.findById(id)
document.concerns = null
documentRepository.save(document)
```

Comment: try this older SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598644/removing-simple-relationships-in-spring-data-neo4j

Comment: Well, my problem is with Spring Boot 2.4 not with previous versions.